# What does "travelling at high speed" in "Look out for the car travelling at high speed" function as?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is there a term used to refer to the following parts of these sentences (in bold):

> Look out for the car **travelling at high speed**.
>
> Catch me **coming in hot**.

I'm not sure if these can be considered adjectival clauses or if there's a better terminology for it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is there a difference between a relative clause (that's had it's whiz deleted?) and a participial clause? [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/286904) (that was linked by John in his answer) seems to be more of a duplicate but the answers don't refer to it as a participial clause which I feel is a more common term than whiz-deletion (based off just google searches), but I don't really know though, I don't have much linguistics background.

Comment: Whiz-deletion has (according to some analyses) led to the whotsit here. 'travelling at high speed' was classically called a participle phrase, then re-analysed as a participle/participial clause. Look at @BillJ's answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327729/what-is-the-difference-between-the-two-sentences-crying-kid-and-kid-crying/327767#327767) for the CGEL approach. / Look up the terms here on ELU; this has been covered many times. You can also cover the basics at say [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-phrase-1691588).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence, it functions as an adjective *(answering the question which car to look for)*.  It is referred to as a  **participial phrase**.

See:

[Purdue](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/02/)

As to whether it is better to call it an *adjectival phrase* or a *participial phrase*, I would pick the latter since both its adjectival role and verbal category are specified.